# iOS 6.1 times out with delivered app, but not on app by Xcode

Tags: ios, ios6, iphone-5

I have an app that got successfully approved by apple and its available thru the App Store.
Installing the app thru the app store works to login and get the initial data, but when you push the refresh button the app just goes to an infinite loop of never finishing to download data.
There's no crash, no timeout message, no error...it just continues to "refresh" for several minutes.

The exact same app installed on the exact same phone (2 phones doing the same) with Xcode 4.5 and 4.6 RP3 have no issues at all. The refresh this way only takes about 10 seconds.
Same thing with emulator on all versions of iOS.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notify users/customers in App Description, and re-submit the App. Maybe a mistake sneaked in before you submitted.

Comment: Yeah that's my only approach to it, but I wanted to know if there's any known issue like this that could prevent me to for having to wait 5 more days for an update.